# Place box outside of parent

Tags: css, flexbox

I have an absolutely positioned div containing two divs side by side. When the left div is removed, the right one appears to jump to the left.

Before:

```
..AABB...
```

After:

```
..BB.....
```

After (desired behaviour):

```
....BB...
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/rb3erkqc/10/

To fix this, I want to be able to absolutely position the right div and have the left one follow along.

The easiest way I can imagine is setting the left margin of A to the negative size of A, but I don't think that's possible, because the size of A is unknown and can change.

Comment: have you tried adding a class upon removing other div where the position is set to absolute? please provide more details and/or some code and I will see if I can help

Comment: please edit post to show details as it is unclear to what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @blayderunner123 better?

Comment: that is better. but would like to see code. I can try but without seeing the code to see what is being executed it is almost impossible

Comment: @blayderunner123 I'll try to make a JSfiddle out of it. Giving my exact code would be unhelpful as it is complicated for completely unrelated reasons.

Comment: well took a shot regardless. however, when you get the code together I will better be able to assist

Comment: @blayderunner123 added fiddle

Comment: working it now. give me a few

Comment: see answer below. I just added to original answer

Comment: that should do it! see Update 2 [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639799/place-box-outside-of-parent/#answer-49639944)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that one can use absolute positioning to make not affect the parent box and then use a css transform to move based on the object's size.

I also added centering for the element outside the box to demonstrate the generality of this approach. Some overflow handling may be necessary in cases where the right side is smaller.

```css
.abspos {
  position: absolute;
  left: 106px;
  top: 57px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.t {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-100%);
  
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.t > div {
  background-color: red;
}

.e {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Just a hack to be able to toggle asd*/
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: -30px;
}

input:checked + .t {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class=abspos>
<input type=checkbox>
<div class=t><div>asd</div></div>
<div class=e>fasd<br>lova</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: makes sense. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

without knowing more, here is my shot in the dark

```js
$('.container').click(function(){
  $('.container div:first-child').remove();
  $('.container div:nth-child(1)').remove();
});
```

```css
.container {  
  display: flex;  
  align-items: center;  
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}  
.container > * {  
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <p>Div A</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Div A</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Div B</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Div B</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

### Edit after code snippet was provided:

```css
.abspos {
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.abspos>*:not(input) {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.t {
  background-color: red;
}

.e {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/* Just a hack to be able to toggle asd*/

input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

input:checked+.t {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <div class=abspos>
    <input type=checkbox>
    <div class=t>asd</div>
    <div class=e>fasd</div>
  </div>
```

### Update 2 with minor changes:

changed `display:none` to `visibility:hidden`

this removes the element from the DOM allowing you to manipulate the `<div class='.e'></div>`

see fiddle below

```css
.abspos {
  margin-top: 10%;
  display: flex;  
  align-items: center;  
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}
.abspos > *:not(input){
  position: relative; 
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.t {
  background-color: red;
}

.e {
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* Just a hack to be able to toggle asd*/
input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

input:checked + .t {
  visibility:hidden; /*remove element from dom to manipulate remaining div*/
}
```

```html
<div class=abspos>
  <input type=checkbox>
  <div class=t>asd</div>
  <div class=e>fasd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please vote up if helpful. please mark as answer if this help provide solution

Comment: Sorry, but this does not solve my problem. I want fasd to stay where it is even when asd changes size. Besides, hiding asd does not work for my purposes. The box has to shrink when asd disappears.

Comment: In case you are wondering what the purpose of all this is: fasd is an expression in a visual programming language, and asd is its type. As the expression is edited, the type can change. When the expression is dropped into another expression, the type is no longer displayed.

Comment: that is more helpful. FASD does stay where it is. Now, you said type is no longer displayed; does that mean it does not exist any longer or it is say commented out, or is it just hidden?

Comment: I figured out how to do this. Only downside is having to use css transforms. Will write answer.

Comment: don't you hate that. glad you worked it out. looking forward to your answer so I may see it in action